# C# WPF Want to store data in a class and use it in multiple different classes in different wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 classes. 1st stores info, 2nd assigns info to 1nd class, 3rd reads the info from the 1st class.

1st Class, not assigned to any WPF window

```
public class ProfileInfo //Used to store Name and Surname Data
    {
        public string User_Name { get; set; }
        public string User_Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

2nd Class, located in WPF window 1

```
public class InsertInfo //Reads data and stores it in Class 1
    {
        ProfileInfo p = new ProfileInfo();
        p.User_Name = "Bob"; //Example value but normally is read from db
        p.User_Surname = "Jhones"; //Example value but normally is read from db
    }
```

3rd Class, located in WPF window 2

```
public class ReadInfo //Reads data from Class 1 and displays it using MessageBox.Show
    {
        ProfileInfo p = new ProfileInfo();
        MessageBox.Show(p.User_Name); // I want this to display Bob but it displays an empty value
        MessageBox.Show(p.User_Surname);
    }
```

I want Class 1 to store the information until i end the program so that i can retrieve the data in multiple classes.

As i understand this doesn't work because in the 3rd Class im calling for a completely different instance of Class 1 that has no data stored in it??? If so how do i make this work?

I have looked all over the internet for a way to share data between classes but everything seems so difficult and not understandable. Im a beginner so please try to explain it in not so technical language if possible.

Comment: If you're searching the internet, what you're interested in is the *"Singleton Pattern"*. PS: "patterns" are common solutions to common programming problems (this "one instance providing data to everyone" is one of the most common thing you'll ever encounter). Not to be confused with the "god object" anti-pattern.

Comment: So you want a single object that stores information only 1 time? Look up C# Static keyword.    Static members / static functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create an instance of `ProfileInfo` **inside**  your `InsertInfo` class but in the 3rd class, `ReadInfo`, you create another `ProfileInfo` instance which is by default, empty. I do not know the details of your system but what you could try is make the `ProfileInfo` field inside your `InsertInfo` class a static [Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property) and then you could access it from your other classes:

```
public class InsertInfo
{
    private static ProfileInfo p = new ProfileInfo();
    public static ProfileInfo P { get { return p; } }

    public void AssignProfileInfo(string username, string surname)
    {
        p.User_Name = username;
        p.User_Surname = surname;
    }
}
```

And then, to access the stored ProfileInfo you could access the static property:

```
public class ReadInfo
{
    ProfileInfo p = InsertInfo.P;

    public void ShowInfo()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(p.User_Name); 
        MessageBox.Show(p.User_Surname);
    }
}
```